# Function not recognized after upgrading lucee

Tags: java, coldfusion, date-formatting, lucee

I'm facing an issue since I did an upgrade from lucee server 5.3.2 to 5.3.8

The problem comes here with the function lsdateformat(). This is how it is used :

```
dateIssue.lsDateFormat('short')
```

After changing it to

```
dateIssue.lsDateFormat(dateIssue, 'short')
```

it seems to work. The problem is that before this upgrade, everything worked fine and changing it in all the code is a huge work.

I tried to see between which versions the error pops up and it is from the version 5.3.3

The error triggered is

```
The function [lsDateFormat] does not exist in the String, but there is a similar function with name [listItemTrim] available.
```

After looking at the release notes, I could not notice what can be causing this

Thanks for your help

Comment: That error message would suggest it thinks you "date" is a string as it's offering a string object member function as a suggestion.

Comment: And it's worth nothing that if you did a cfdump or writedump of that dateissue variable, in Lucee at least the output would CONFIRM what type the CFML is inferring that value to be. As for "what changed" from the one version of Lucee to the next, you'd want to look at what creates that variable, as THAT seems to be where the "change" happened.

Answer (score 3):

So, that it appears to be the case it thinks it is a string, compare this:

https://trycf.com/gist/4ddcc2123a69a9c410e366c7b8929805/lucee5?theme=monokai

to this:

https://trycf.com/gist/9e71fa25b4f9d38dfe43625b31b3f66c/lucee5?theme=monokai

The first errors with your error message, the second works.

To use the date object functions, the object needs to be a date, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

What I figured it out since the value comes from the database, in the version 5.3.2, the value returned is sometimes null which is correct since we compare with !isNull(). With the update, this value is not anymore NULL but an empty string.

Between the version 5.3.2 and 5.3.3, there’s modification according to the NULL support

See https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-2236

In Lucee Server, we need to enable the full support to avoid the issue